# How to make script run on system start/user login via terminal

Tags: macos, command-line, python

I have Mac OS PC, let's name it PC1, and I have Linux PC (PC2), on Mac os PC I have python script(reverse shell), I need to make it run on system start or user login(no matter) threw terminal, I have sudo access to Mac OS terminal from my Linux, so how can I do it?

Comment: Welcome to Ask Different. Are you basically asking how macOS shell dot files run to set up environment or how to make a `launchd` task on Mac? With PC and PC1 and PC2 what “do it” means isn’t clear at all to me.

Comment: I mean, how can I make python run on system startup using only terminal

Comment: Please *edit* instead of deleting and reasking. We lose track of the things discussed in the comments otherwise

Comment: If you do, please also explain with which step you are struggling: remote login from Linux to Mac, using launchd/cron on macOS, getting your script to work etc